# Convex polygons with a specified number of interior points

Tags: geometry, reference-request, polygons, convex-geometry

Is there a systematic classification of (2d, i.e. planar) convex polygons with a specific number of interior points?

If someone has suggestions for references, please let me know!

I am aware of a classification of 16 convex polyhedra in 2 dimensions with one interior point that appears in the context of toric geometry (e.g. the book on toric geometry by Cox, Little, and Schenck). What I'm seeking is a generalization of this to polygons with $\geq 2$ interior points.